# Modify my query to extract the data with latest "logcreateddate"

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using Sql Server Management Studio 2012 and I have created a sql query which can be found below:

```
SELECT
    workorder.wonum as "WorkOrderNo",
    Workorder.description as "WorkorderDescription",
    Workorder.status as "WOstatus",
    Workorder.reportdate as "WOReportedDate",
    workorder.plusgmatrixprior as "WOPriority",
    wfassignment.startdate as "WorkflowStartDate",
    wfassignment.assigncode as "AssignedToLoginID",
    wfassignment.description as "AssignmentDescription",
    worklog.createby as "LogEnteredby",
    worklog.createdate as "LogCreatedDate",
    worklog.eventcode as "EventCode",
    worklog.logtype as "LogType",
    worklog.delayed as "ReasonforDelay",
    worklog.description as "LogDescription",
    worklog.description_long as "LoglongDescription"
FROM
    wfassignment, 
    workorder, 
    worklog
WHERE
    wfassignment.ownertable = 'workorder'
    AND wfassignment.ownerid = workorder.workorderid
    AND worklog.recordkey = workorder.wonum
    AND worklog.class = workorder.woclass
    AND workorder.siteid = 'adrd'
    AND wfassignment.assignstatus = 'active'
    AND wfassignment.assigncode = 'TRW4074'
    AND worklog.createby = 'TRW4074'
ORDER BY 
    workorder.wonum desc;
```

I have ran the query. The Output table contains some rows having same `WorkOrderNo` against different `LogCreatedDate`.

I want to obtain all fields in above query with latest or maximum `LogCreatedDate`.

Note: I have tried using `max()` function and `group by`. But it did not work because other fields are not unique. Hence the output is containing duplicates of `WorkOrderNo`.

Please help modifying the above query or provide me the suggestion to obtain all fields with the latest date.

Answer (score 1):

Use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT
    wo.wonum AS "WorkOrderNo",
    wo.description AS "WorkorderDescription",
    wo.status AS "WOstatus",
    wo.reportdate AS "WOReportedDate",
    wo.plusgmatrixprior AS "WOPriority",
    wa.startdate AS "WorkflowStartDate",
    wa.assigncode AS "AssignedToLoginID",
    wa.description AS "AssignmentDescription",
    wl.createby AS "LogEnteredby",
    wl.createdate AS "LogCreatedDate",
    wl.eventcode AS "EventCode",
    wl.logtype AS "LogType",
    wl.delayed AS "ReasonforDelay",
    wl.description AS "LogDescription",
    wl.description_long AS "LoglongDescription"
FROM wfassignment wa
JOIN workorder wo ON wa.ownerid = wo.workorderid
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM worklog wl 
            WHERE wl.recordkey = wo.wonum AND 
                  wl.class = wo.woclass AND 
                  wl.createby = 'TRW4074' 
            ORDER BY wl.createdate DESC) wl
WHERE wa.ownertable = 'workorder' AND 
      wo.siteid = 'adrd' AND 
      wa.assignstatus = 'active' AND 
      wa.assigncode = 'TRW4074'
```